# For filtering connections to Tor with ipset, do I need to set the protocol to tcp?

Tags: onion-routing, linux, network-configuration, transparent-proxy

I wrote a little tool to generate an ipset of all Tor nodes in order to filter connections (eg. relay all non Tor traffic through Tor).

In the ipset restore file, do I need to specify a protocol or not?
I'm not sure if Tor ever uses anything else than tcp...

`add [setName] [ip],tcp:[port] -exist`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tor clients only use TCP to connect to nodes. hash:ip,port defaults to TCP, so you don't need to specify a protocol.

You may be interested in https://github.com/rustybird/corridor, which builds exactly the ipset you want from the current consensus.